# Incomplete loading of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, loading

Disclosure: I am new to python. I am trying to load a dictionary with files using the hash value as my key and the file path as my value. I added a counter to ensure the dictionary was properly loaded. After running the code below, I have 78 files (Counter) but only 47 for my dictionary length. Why did it not load all 78 files? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)

    for filename in filenames:
        m1 = hashlib.md5(filename)
        hValue = m1.hexdigest()
        pValue = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        myDict[(hValue)]=pValue
        counter +=1

print len(myDict), "Dict Length"
print counter, "counter"
```

Comment: You call `os.path.join` but don't assign the result to anything.  What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 1):

1. You call `os.path.join` but don't keep the value, so your first nested for loop is useless.  I'm not sure what it was meant to do.
2. You don't need to create an md5 hash of the filename, just use the filename as the key for the dict.
3. You are probably missing entries because you have files with the same name in different directories.  Use `os.path.join(dirname, filename)` as the key for the dict.

Update: you're hashing the filename.  To hash the contents:

```
m1 = hashlib.md5(open(filename).read())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer…I thought that the md5 is doing a hash on the complete file and not just the name-is that not the case?  Ultimately, I want to compare file hashes to determine if I have duplicate files and print the path of those duplicates

Comment: @JaridF: If you want to hash the file contents you'd have to actually open the file and read its contents.  `os.path.walk` just gives you the names, not the contents.  (This is a good thing.  What if one of the files is 100GB in size?)

Answer (score 0):

The **dictionary keys need to be unique** (or you will just overwrite the value corresponding to the key), and uniqueness isn't guaranteed by your method.

Since you're just hashing the filenames, if your filenames aren't unique, your hashes won't be either.  Try hashing the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is my first answer in stackoverflow :)

Hi @Jarid F,

I tried writing a complete program so that you can run and see for yourself. Here's the code:

```
import os
import hashlib

myDict = {}
counter = 0
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):    
    for filename in filenames:
        #get the complete file location so that it's unique
        filename_with_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        m1 = hashlib.md5(filename_with_path)
        #to hash the content of the file:
        #m1 = hashlib.md5(open(filename_with_path).read())
        hValue = m1.hexdigest()    
        myDict[hValue] = filename_with_path
        counter += 1

print len(myDict), "Dict Length"
print counter, "counter"
assert counter == len(myDict)
```

To add on a few points which @Ned Batchelder has provided:

- The line `myDict[(hValue)]=pValue` is actually the same as `myDict[hValue] = pValue` but I recommend not adding the `()` in. That will cause confusion later when you start working with tuples
- Hashing the content of the filename may not be want you want, since even if two files are different but they have the same content (like 2 empty files) they will yeild the same hash value. I guess that defeats the purpose you're trying to achieve here. Instead if I may suggest, you could take `hash(hash(file_location)+hash(file_content)+some_secret_key)` to make the hash key better. (Please pardon my cautious in adding the secret key as an extra security measure)

Good luck with your code & welcome to python!